# How to merge more than two videos using FrameRecorder (javacv)?

Tags: java, android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

is there any way to merge more than two videos using javacv open library?

I've tried the below code, but this allows only two videos at a time

```
void merge() {
FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(ffmpeg_link
                + "1.mp4");
        grabber1.start();           
        FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(ffmpeg_link
                + "2.mp4");
        grabber2.start();           
        FrameRecorder recorder2 = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("/mnt/sdcard/"
                + "output.mp4", grabber1.getImageWidth(),
                grabber1.getImageHeight(), grabber1.getAudioChannels());
        recorder2.setFrameRate(grabber1.getFrameRate());
        recorder2.setSampleFormat(grabber1.getSampleFormat());
        recorder2.setSampleRate(grabber1.getSampleRate());          
        recorder2.start();
        Frame frame;
        int j = 0;
        while ((frame = grabber1.grabFrame()) != null) {
            j++;
            recorder2.record(frame);                
        }           
        while ((frame = grabber2.grabFrame()) != null) {
            recorder2.record(frame);                
        }

        recorder2.stop();
        grabber2.stop();
        grabber1.stop();        


}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you havent search in stack overflow or in google.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811181/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-in-java

Comment: i've seen that post, but my requirement is totally different, i need to merge more than two videos into a single video file from my android device.